# milliseconds since unix epoch as @RequestParameter for joda DateTime

Tags: spring-mvc, jodatime

Software stack: Java8, Spring MVC 4.0.5, JodaTime 2.3, Jackson2

The API I'm implementing requests all date-times to be represented as milliseconds since UNIX epoch. For json, it's easy:

```
configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
```

in JodaObjectMapper.
The problem is with `@RequestParam`s. Whenever a Unix timestamp is passed to a controller with
`@RequestParam DateTime date` I get an exception:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.time.DateTime';
  nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException:
    Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam org.joda.time.DateTime for value '1404820782110';
      nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
        Invalid format: "1404820782110" is malformed at "04820782110"
```

Currently I changed `DateTime` to `Long` and do `new DateTime(date)` to get a date-time object. I'm also considering move from epoch timestamps to ISO format which is well supported. But I'd like to know if there is a solution for the initial problem, just in case.

Comment: Use @InitBinder or conversionService

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom Converter:

```
public class StringToJodaDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, DateTime> {

    @Override
    public DateTime convert(String source) {
        return new DateTime(Long.parseLong(source));
    }

}
```

And register it like this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="StringToJodaDateTimeConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```